# Prefix-tree for pairs of elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, trie

I have a nested list:

```
lists = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
         ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e'],
         ['a', 'b', 'd', 'f'],
         ['a', 'b', 'd', 'f', 'h', 'i']]
```

I know how to build a simple prefix-tree:

```
tree = {}
end = "END"
for lst in lists:
    d = tree
    for x in lst:
        d = d.setdefault(x, {})
    d[end] = {}
```

Result:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(tree)
{'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': {'END': {}}},
             'd': {'e': {'END': {}},
                   'f': {'END': {}, 'h': {'i': {'END': {}}}}}}}}
```

Now I can recursively traverse that tree, and whenever a node has only a single child (a sub-dict with just a single element), join those nodes.

```
def join(d, pref=[]):
    if end in d:
        yield [' '.join(pref)] if pref else []
    for k, v in d.items():
        if len(v) == 1:
            for x in join(v, pref + [k]): # add node to prefix
                yield x                   # yield next segment
        else:
            for x in join(v, []):         # reset prefix
                yield [' '.join(pref + [k])] + x # yield node + prefix and next
```

Result:

```
>>> for x in join(tree):
...     print(x)
...
['a b', 'c d']
['a b', 'd', 'e']
['a b', 'd', 'f']
['a b', 'd', 'f', 'h i']
```

What I need is an algorithm where only common **pairs** of elements become single node of the tree. Ideally, the minimum length of a node = n1, the maximum length of a node = n2. Desired output:

```
[['a b', 'c d'],
 ['a b', 'd e'],
 ['a b', 'd f'],
 ['a b', 'd f', 'h i']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just alternate between joining and yielding:

```
def paired(d, _prefix=None):
    if end in d:
        yield [_prefix] if _prefix else []
    for k, v in d.items():
        item = [f'{_prefix} {k}'] if _prefix else []
        for rest in paired(v, None if _prefix else k):
            yield item + rest
```

So at each level, if `_prefix` is set, produce a pair, otherwise leave that level 'empty' and recurse with the current key as the prefix.

This produces your expected output:

```
>>> for path in paired(tree):
...     print(path)
...
['a b', 'c d']
['a b', 'd e']
['a b', 'd f']
['a b', 'd f', 'h i']
```